# Sed command not showing double quotes

Tags: regex, xml, bash, shell, sed

I am using **"sed"** command to replace a string from a ".properties" file in linux shell script. The problem is that it is not showing the double quotes.

Note: I think sed command ignores the double quotes,so is there anyway to explicitly force it to not ignore it.

**"Shell Script File"**

```
#!/bin/bash

# First Script
#Include Properties File
. directoryPaths.properties

sed -i "s#EPOLD#$EPNEW#" *Test*
```

**Properties File:**

```
EPNEW="jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format="pox" "
```

**File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Component">
        <address uri=EPOLD/>
    </endpoint>
```

**Current Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Component">
    <address uri=jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactoryGLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactoryGLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616GLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format=pox />
</endpoint>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Component">
        <address uri="jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactoryGLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactoryGLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616GLBookingService_EPLOCALamp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format="pox" " />
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: That's how quotes work in Bash. `foo="bar"` sets the value of `$foo` to `bar`. If you want it to be `"bar"` use `foo="\"bar\""` or `foo='"bar"'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your variable by inserting literal double quotes:

```
EPNEW='"jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format="pox" "'
```

Your assignment is this:

```
EPNEW="jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format="pox" "
```

Which will leave this value in `EPNEW`:

```
jms:/Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue format=pox
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with quotes in sed:

```
sed -i "s#EPOLD#\"$EPNEW\"#" *Test*
```

Your quotes is getting missed when you source your properties file and not ignored by sed.